# How would I change the class of an input as the user types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input, passwords

I'm trying to change the colour of a password confirmation input as the user types into it. If it matches, the border goes green, if it doesn't, it goes red.

Here is the JQuery:

```
var createPass = $("#createPass").val();
var confirmPass = $("#confirmPass").val();

$("#confirmPass").keydown(function() {

   if(confirmPass == createPass && confirmPass != "") {
      confirmPass.addClass("inputCorrect")
   } else {
      confirmPass.addClass("inputIncorect");
   }
});
```

The html:

```
<label for="passWord">Create Password</label>
<input type="password" id="createPass" name="passWord" class="inputBox"  placeholder="Minimum 8 characters" required><br>

<label>Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" id="confirmPass" class="inputBox" required>
```

And the CSS:

```
input.passCorrect {
   border: 1px solid #00cc00;
}

input.passIncorrect {
   border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

I've also tried the following JQuery first, but it seemed a bit long for the job:

```
$("input[id=confirmPass").keyup(function() {

   if ($("input[id=confirmPass]").val() == $("input[id=createPass]").val()) {

       ($("input[id=confirmPass]").removeClass("passIncorrect"));
       ($("input[id=confirmPass]").addClass("passCorrect"));

   }

   if ($("input[id=confirmPass]").val() != $("input[id=createPass]").val() && ($("input[id=confirmPass]") != "")) {

       ($("input[id=confirmPass]").removeClass("passCorrect"));
       ($("input[id=confirmPass]").addClass("passIncorrect"));

   }

});
```

I've tried using `.keyup()`, `.keydown()`, `.keypress()`, `.change()`, and have renamed just about every class, id and variable but I've had no success! It's in a separate `.js` file, and I've tried it with and without `$(document).ready()` and it doesn't work. I've also tried using `.css()` as opposed to `.addClass` and `.removeClass`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't you get the "confirmPass" value each time a key is pressed in your first exemple, to get the actual one ?

Comment: try with onInput event

Comment: Suggestions: 1) you spelled "incorrect" incorrectly in "addClass". 2) if you want help on this I would recommend creating a JSFiddle or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed Javascript that will make it work:

```
var createPass = $("#createPass");
var confirmPass = $("#confirmPass");

confirmPass.keydown(function() {
    // Remove both classes
   confirmPass.removeClass("passCorrect passIncorrect");

   // Add the appropriate class
   if (confirmPass.val() == createPass.val() && confirmPass.val() != "") {
      confirmPass.addClass("passCorrect");
   } else {
      confirmPass.addClass("passIncorrect");
   }
});
```

Here are the things that weren't working beforehand:

- When executing the code `confirmPass.addClass("inputCorrect")`, you were adding a class to an integer value.
- In your javascript, you added the classes 'inputCorrect' and 'inputIncorrect', but in your CSS you refer to the classes as 'passCorrect' and 'passIncorrect'.
- You need to get the value of createPass and confirmPass each time the user presses a key, or else the two variables you declare at the beginning will always contain the initial value of the two inputs.
- You need to remove the input's class each time the user presses a key, or else both classes will apply to the input.

Comment: Almost. You need to remove class 'passIncorrect' before adding 'passCorrect'. It's actually a good idea to remove class 'passIncorrect' for each cycle and add it again when the conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks Asher!
It's not working on my website but it's doing exactly what I want in the fiddle. I think it might be something else that's wrong as no simple tests are working either, with JavaScript or JQuery. I'll have to dig a bit deeper but I'll definitely be using this snippet once it's all fixed.